# Do anybody have the code for recording android screen with audio?

Tags: android, screen, recording

I want to make an mp4 video of an activity on android device. Do anybody have the code or suggestions for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this in code, but you can use adb from the Android SDK to do this:

1. Enable debugging
2. Install SDK (I presume this is already done)
3. Plug your phone in to your computer
4. After checking the phone is seen by your computer with adb devices (command prompt inside the SDK installation directory), run:
   **adb shell screenrecord --verbose ./sdcard/screencast-video.mp4**

Here's the source for these steps:
http://www.labnol.org/software/record-android-screencast/4929/